# BelongsToMany independent child's relations - Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

**Model structure**:

`FoodCategory` - hasMany: `Food`

`Food` - belongsToMany: `AccessoryGroup` | belongsTo: `FoodCategory`

`AccessoryGroup` - hasMany: `Accessory` | belongsToMany: `Food`

`Accessory` - belongsTo: `AccessoryGroup`

```
$foodCategories = FoodCategory
  ::with([
   'foods',
   'foods.accessory_groups',
   'foods.accessory_groups.accessories',
  ])
  ->get();
```

```
$foodCategories->each(function($foodCategory) {
  $foodCategoryId = $foodCategory->id;
  $foodCategory->foods->each(function($food) use( $foodCategoryId ) {
    $food->accessory_groups->each(function($accessoryGroup) use( $foodCategoryId ) {

      $accessoryGroup->accessories->each(function($accessory) use( $foodCategoryId ) {

        // accessory - not unique by different food grandparent realation
        $accessory->parent_food_category_id = $foodCategoryId;

      });

    });
  });
});
```

Problem is when i set `$accessory->parent_food_category_id = $foodCategoryId;` last **same** accessory overrides `parent_food_category_id` value for "all accessories" *(with same id)* - *(diffrent `food` grandparent)*.

Is it possible to easily "clone" `belongsToMany` relation (in this case `accessory_groups`). And than when you change their child (`accessory`), to not change on all same `accessories` *(with same id)*.

Needed optimized solution. Not to call separate sql for every `food` -> `accessory_group` relation *(One of the solutions for this problem)*

Answer (score 0):

My Solution (use **replicate** Model method)

```
$foodCategories->each(function($foodCategory) {
  $foodCategoryId = $foodCategory->id;
  $foodCategory->foods->each(function($food) use( $foodCategoryId ) {
    $food->accessory_groups->each(function($accessoryGroup) use( $foodCategoryId ) {

      $accessoryGroup->accessories->each(function($accessory, $index) use( $foodCategoryId, $accessoryGroup ) {
    
    // Create clone
        $accessoryClone = $accessory->replicate();
        $accessoryClone->parent_food_category_id = $foodCategoryId;
    
    // OVERRIDE existing accessory with cloned
        $accessoryGroup->accessories[$index] = $accessoryClone;

      });

    });
  });
});
```